# Vertical and horizontal scroll-bars showing up on the screen

Tags: javascript, canvas

Whilst doing a simple canvas set up in JS, i used the following code:

```
var board;
var context;
window.onload = function(){
    board = document.getElementById("board");
    context = board.getContext("2d");
    setInterval(update, 1);
}
function update(){
    board.width = window.innerWidth;
    board.height = window.innerHeight;
    
    context.fillStyle = "black";
    context.fillRect(0,0,board.width,board.height)
}
```

However, when I run this code, while the canvas does show up, 2 scrollbars show up. How can I remove them?

I have attempted to get the window size in different ways, as i thought it was just a bit enlarged. However, these scrollbars still show up every time.

Comment: add the style `overflow: none` to your canvas or whatever is showing the scrollbars.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following css styling, I was able to remove the scroll bar

```
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;`enter code here`
}
#board {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: OP’s issue is the default margin on body, so setting it to 0 as you suggest should help. There’s no reason to use absolute positioning, though. Plus, `height: 100%` won’t do much when body’s height is still small. You want board to be 100vw wide and 100vh high.